# Why does auto response rules create an email on that particular case?

Tags: email2case, servicecloud

I have email-to-case & Auto Response rules setup in my org. I would like to know why the auto response rules always create an outgoing (sent) email record in my case? How can I disable that? Please refer below:

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is by design - The `Case` related List `EmailMessages` is meant to show all inbound/outbound messages and if you have an autoresponse rule, you have to supply an email template for each rule - hence the email showing up here.

If you want to remove the auto-response `EmailMessage` from the case's related list (to avoid clutter), you will need an after insert trigger on SObject `EMailMessage` that detects that the `EmailMessage` is from the autoresponse rule's template (and from no other action), and then does a DML delete.

Something like this:

```
trigger removeEmailCaseClutter on EmailMessage (after insert) {
    List<EmailMessage> emDelList = new List<EmailMessage> ();
    for (EmailMessage em : Trigger.new)   // bulkified
       if (em.subject.contains('Auto acknowledgement'))
          emDelList.add(em);

    delete emDelList;   // delete all qualifying emailMessages
}
```

Note (confusingly), that SObject `EmailMessage` is only used for `Case` emails; it is unrelated to emails sent by Tasks

I've omitted try-catches, and normally my triggers would delegate to a class to do the work but you get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a Trigger (IMHO) to remove this seems like a lot of extra 
weight when this can be easily solved with a workflow. I'm assuming of course that this is an automated email that lets' your customer know you created a case for them and someone will be in touch or something like that....

All you have to do is create a workflow and when the case is created you can fire off an email to your customer - use the same template assignment rules is using and presto - you have an auto reply - and this one will not be added to the case feed because it's running from a workflow outside of the feed publisher. I can send you more details if you would like.... just shout..

Best,
KEvin

Comment: so you are saying (1) turn off/don't use Case auto-response rules and (2) use a workflow rule w/ email alert instead to send ack to the customer.  This way, `EmailMessage`'s related list doesn't show the ack?